# Variables for objects -- Java

Tags: java, oop, object

I have two classes, `Main.java` and `Car.java`

`Main.java`:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Car ferrari = new Car(18, 25.43);
        System.out.println(ferrari.efficiency);
    }
}
```

`Car.java`:

```
class Car
{
    public Car(double mpg, double initFuel)
    {
        double efficiency = mpg;
        double fuel = initFuel;
    }
}
```

I obviously tried to assign efficiency to the first constructor passed in when creating the object, but that doesn't seem to work (i.e. the variable is not found when I use the `println` in Main.java). How do I assign variables to objects to be referenced later?

Comment: `efficiency` and `fuel` must be defined as members. In your example they are just local variables of the constructor.

Comment: @Benoit - How do I do this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Previous link was to the wrong page. New link should be correct.

Comment: @Slaw The previous link seemed to work for me! It _did_ lead me to the correct answer...

Comment: The problem was the previous link dealt specifically with `static` fields/methods, which is not what you want here. The new link points to pages that deal with instance fields/methods; read the sub-sections of the page I linked to as well (you can see all the links on the left of the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using local variables in your `Car`'s constructor. Their lifecycle bounded within your constructor. Just declare your members in your class and use getters and setters to access them.

```
class Car
{
    private double efficiency;
    private double fuel;

    public Car(double mpg, double initFuel)
    {
        this.efficiency = mpg;
        this.fuel = initFuel;
    }

    public void setEfficiency(double efficiency) {
        this.efficiency = efficiency;
    }

    public double getEfficiency() {
        return efficiency;
    }

    // Same thing for fuel...
}
```

And in your `Main`:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Car ferrari = new Car(18, 25.43);
        System.out.println(ferrari.getEfficiency());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make efficiency and fuel global to your class rather than local to your constructor.
`Main.java`

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Car ferrari = new Car(18, 25.43);
        System.out.println(ferrari.efficiency);
    }
}
```

`Car.java`

```
public class Car
{
    public double efficiency;
    public double fuel;
    public Car(double mpg, double initFuel)
    {
        efficiency = mpg;
        fuel = initFuel;
    }
}
```

That should work. But you can make the instance variables private instead of public and use setters/getters
Also set your Main and Car to public so they can be accessible/instantiated from another class.
`Main.java`

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Car ferrari = new Car(18, 25.43);
        System.out.println(ferrari.getEfficiency());
    }
}
```

`Car.java`

```
public class Car
{
    private double efficiency;
    private double fuel;
    public Car(double mpg, double initFuel)
    {
        efficiency = mpg;
        fuel = initFuel;
    }
    public double getEfficiency(){
        return efficiency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `Car` class to:

```
class Car
{ 
    private double efficiency;
    private double fuel;

    public Car(double mpg, double initFuel)
    {
        this.efficiency = mpg;
        this.fuel = initFuel;
    }
}
```

You need to declare the variables on the `Class` scope instead of the local scope when using a variable for an instantiated Object.  These variables typically are set from the Constructor so they can be accessed later from the Object itself.

Most of the time these are also declared as `private` with a separate method to `get` and `set` them instead of directly accessing them.

**Example:**

```
public double getEfficiency(){
    return this.efficiency;    
}
public void setEfficiency(double mpg){
    this.efficiency = mpg;
}
```

Most IDE's can auto generate Getters and Setters for you so you do not need to hand write them for every variable.

To use the getter/setter you call the method from an instance of the class rather than using the variable directly:

```
Car tesla = new Car(35.5, 90.5);

tesla.efficiency = 15.5; //YOU CAN'T DO THIS
tesla.setEfficiency(15.5); //Do this instead

System.out.println(tesla.getEfficiency()); //Will print 15.5
```

Comment: Wrong return type in the getter/setter